# Swift Выполнение функции после некого времени

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Помогите как выполнит какую-то функцию через определенный промежуток времени. Например сделать запрос через 120сек секунд при нажатие кнопки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать метод `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`
Пример:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 120.0) - выполнить через 120 сек.
{
   SomeMethod()
}
```